# How to arrange and group elemets by using predefined rule?

Tags: xml, xslt

Good day!

I'm trying to build up an xsl transformation file that do the next:

There is an element that has a bunch of child elements of the type Characteristic. Each of them has its unique Name. 
I also have a list that describes the logical connection between some of Names and a certain named Characteristic sets (called Datasets):

CharacteristicName    :   DatasetName  
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
Att1_DS1                 : DS1
Att2_DS1                 : DS1
Att1_DS2                 : DS2
Att2_DS2                 : DS2

I have to transform the xml so the main element should get new elements of type `<Dataset>`. These Dataset with ids from the table should appear if the listed Characteristic Names appear in the source document. And then the corresponding Characteristics are copyed to these Dataset elements/

If some Characteristic Name  is not listed in the table so it should be placed in the Dataset with the id "Other"

Source XML:

```
<Object>
    <ID>Obj1</ID>

    <!--DS1-->     
    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att1_DS1</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <!--DS2-->
    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att1_DS2</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <!--DS1-->  
    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att2_DS1</Name>
        <Value>ABC</Value>
    </Characteristic>       

    <!--DS2-->
    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att2_DS2</Name>
        <Value>ABC</Value>
    </Characteristic>   

            <!--Other-->
    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att3_NN</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>   

</Object>
```

It should be transformed to:

```
<Object>
    <ID>Obj1</ID>

    <Dataset id="DS1">
        <Characteristic>
            <Name>Att1_DS1</Name>
            <Value>25</Value>
        </Characteristic>
        <Characteristic>
            <Name>Att2_DS1</Name>
            <Value>ABC</Value>
        </Characteristic>
    </Dataset>

    <Dataset id="DS2">
        <Characteristic>
            <Name>Att1_DS1</Name>
            <Value>25</Value>
        </Characteristic>
        <Characteristic>
            <Name>Att2_DS1</Name>
            <Value>ABC</Value>
        </Characteristic>
    </Dataset>

    <Dataset id="Other">
        <Characteristic>
            <Name>Att3_NN</Name>
            <Value>25</Value>
        </Characteristic>
    </Dataset>

</Object>
```

Could you please help me doing these. Any tips or ideas which direction should I move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <my:datasets>
       <ds>
         <id>DS1</id>
         <n>Att1_DS1</n>
         <n>Att2_DS1</n>
       </ds>
       <ds>
         <id>DS2</id>
         <n>Att1_DS2</n>
         <n>Att2_DS2</n>
       </ds>
       <ds>
         <id>other</id>
         <n>Att3_NN</n>
       </ds>
      </my:datasets>

      <xsl:variable name="vDS" select="document('')/*/my:datasets/*"/>

      <xsl:template match="/*">
       <Object>
         <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>

         <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "$vDS[n = current()/Characteristic/Name]">
          <xsl:with-param name="pChars" select="Characteristic"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </Object>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ds">
       <xsl:param name="pChars"/>
        <Dataset id="{id}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="$pChars[Name = current()/n]"/>
        </Dataset>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Object>
    <ID>Obj1</ID>

    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att1_DS1</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att1_DS2</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att2_DS1</Name>
        <Value>ABC</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att2_DS2</Name>
        <Value>ABC</Value>
    </Characteristic>

    <Characteristic>
        <Name>Att3_NN</Name>
        <Value>25</Value>
    </Characteristic>
</Object>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Object>
   <ID>Obj1</ID>
   <Dataset id="DS1">
      <Characteristic>
         <Name>Att1_DS1</Name>
         <Value>25</Value>
      </Characteristic>
      <Characteristic>
         <Name>Att2_DS1</Name>
         <Value>ABC</Value>
      </Characteristic>
   </Dataset>
   <Dataset id="DS2">
      <Characteristic>
         <Name>Att1_DS2</Name>
         <Value>25</Value>
      </Characteristic>
      <Characteristic>
         <Name>Att2_DS2</Name>
         <Value>ABC</Value>
      </Characteristic>
   </Dataset>
   <Dataset id="other">
      <Characteristic>
         <Name>Att3_NN</Name>
         <Value>25</Value>
      </Characteristic>
   </Dataset>
</Object>
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but seems that I explained my task not so clearly(( The point is that Characteristic Names are not always have the name of the Dataset they belong to in their names. And it means that I have to somehow store a dictionary from which the code will find the relations.

Comment: @OlegMudrov: Was my answer useful to you and do you still have problems?

Comment: sorry for my absence - I just have got a chance to check out your solution. This is brilliant, thank you very much; it really helps me in my project! You are just a real guru in XML ;)